Can't build crate gmp_mpfr_sys on windows using msys2
I have installed msys2 and under the MinGW 64 have installed:

mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain.
mingw-w64-x86_64-rust
I have installed rust via rustup with  x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

cargo build fails on gmp-mpfr-sys
Rust version: rustc 1.80.1 (3f5fd8dd4 2024-08-06) (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
Default host: x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
Cargo: cargo 1.80.1 (376290515 2024-07-16)
It fails to build the crate on gmp-mpfr-sys(build)
thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\steph\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\gmp-mpfr-sys-1.6.4\build.rs:1214:29:
  Unable to execute: "cp" "-R" "C:\\Users\\steph\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\\gmp-mpfr-sys-1.6.4\\gmp-6.3.0-c" "C:\\msys64\\home\\steph\\tdb_VIP\\target\\release\\build\\gmp-mpfr-sys-ff388fc2f9be9ff3\\out\\build\\gmp-src"
  stack backtrace:
     0: rust_begin_unwind
     1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
     2: build_script_build::execute::{{closure}}
     3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap_or_else
     4: build_script_build::execute
     5: build_script_build::link_dir
     6: build_script_build::compile_libs
     7: build_script_build::main
     8: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
  note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

T thought I had correctly followed the instructions to build gmp-mpfr-sys on windows.
What am I doing wrong?

Doesn't cp expect forward slashes / as path separator?
